# MovieClip not showing the right frame

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

I currently have a MovieClip with the instance name: "powerbar".  It has a total of 6 frames, and depending on a certain criteria, I want it to show a specific frame.  Here is my code:

```
            if(char.throwing) {
            var pressLength:Number = getTimer()-startPress;

            if(pressLength >= 400) {
                powerbar.gotoAndPlay(6);
                trace("more than 400 " +String(powerbar.currentFrame));
            }
            else if(pressLength >= 300) {
                powerbar.gotoAndPlay(5);
                trace("more than 300 " +String(powerbar.currentFrame));
            }
            else if(pressLength >= 200) {
                powerbar.gotoAndPlay(4);
                trace("more than 200 " +String(powerbar.currentFrame));
            }
            else if(pressLength >= 100) {
                powerbar.gotoAndPlay(3);
                trace("more than 100 " +String(powerbar.currentFrame));
            }
            else if(pressLength >= 50) {
                powerbar.gotoAndPlay(2);
                trace("more than 50 " +String(powerbar.currentFrame));
            }
            else if(pressLength >= 25) {
                powerbar.gotoAndPlay(1);
                trace("more than 25 " +String(powerbar.currentFrame));
            }
            else if(pressLength >= 0) {

                powerbar.gotoAndPlay(1);
            }
```

It compiles fine, there are no errors at run time, I even checked to see if my if statements are working depending on what I needed here, and I made sure I was referencing the right movie clip (I traced the movie clip's x location and it was the right one).  I even traced if it is going to that frame by tracing (power bar.currentFrame) and it shows that it has progressed to that frame, though it doesn't show that in the animation.  **I also tried gotoAndStop, and it still didn't work...** Please help!

Comment: gotoAndStop instead of gotoAndPlay ?

Comment: I tried that in the beginning and it didn't work, and I just changed it now and it still didn't work

Comment: Your mistake is outside of that code. Meaning you have probably done something else which is wrong. Most likely you have misunderstood how animations work in flash. Or what you thought was gonna happen when you started your animation. Or powerbar is not linked to right movieclip, or presslength is not reset between calls or something completely different is wrong. What I'm trying to say is that nothing is wrong with that code and thus no one will be able to help you achieve what you want given your explanation.

Comment: What happens if pressLength is a negative Number? You aren't handling this condition. Trace startPress and pressLength just to be sure. Also, as Lee Burrows pointed out, gotoAndStop() has the behaviour you want.

Comment: Try to insert keyframes on each frame to break the tween.

Answer (score 0):

```
        var pressLength:Number = getTimer()-startPress;

        //enterFrame/or keypress  function here:)
        if(char.throwing) {
        throwing_function();
        }

        function throwing_function (){
        if(pressLength >= 25 && pressLength<=49) { // check both conditions
            powerbar.gotoAndStop(2);
            trace("more than 25 but less than 50")
            trace(pressLength.toString) // i think
        }
        else if(pressLength >= 50 && pressLenght<=74) {check both conditions are good
            powerbar.gotoAndStop(3);
            trace("more than 50 but less than 75 ")
       }
       }

       etc......
```

But there are better ways to approach this, i thought i would stick with your theme

By checking only one condition you have problems, i made this mistake a long time ago on a progress bar loading assets.